# Prometheus дублирует значения

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana

Всем привет. Проблема заключается вот в чем. В prometheus добавлены метрики. В тесте работает все правильно! После выкатки в прод что то происходит со значениями... Ощущение, что prometheus тянет значение с нескольких переменных.

[image: Сначала показывает это]

потом показывает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и так скачут значения туда сюда. При наступлении событий счетчики нормально инкрементируются. В чем может быть проблема? В графане вот так рисует.

[image: Графана график]

Comment: Так может быть, у вас и в самом деле несколько переменных? Где, как и чем вы создаёте и инкрементируете эту метрику?

Comment: Точнее, важно даже не это. Как и чем вы запускаете веб-сервер, который считает эту метрику (сервлет или что там у вас)? Вероятно, в различиях параметров запуска между тестом и продом и кроется причина

Comment: Просто есть сервис работающий на 2х машинах. Прометеус вместо объединения значений, он между ними просто скачет

Comment: Как именно прометеус обращается за метриками к этим двум машинам? Знает ли он, что машин две?

Comment: Думаю знает, так как в других сервисах сбор метрик тем же прометеусом идет правильно

Comment: По описанию «Думаю знает» мы никак не сможем проанализировать ситуацию и помочь

Comment: Как посмотреть? Просто этим занимались девопсы, я впервые этим занимаюсь. Выяснилось, что на тесте и на проде прометеус работает одинаково. Значения скачут везде. Но в графане отображается по разному. Может проблема в настройках графаны?